# How I can validate letters in c ++ with Try-catch?

Tags: c++, validation, oop, try-catch

I would like to improve the code below. I would like to use try-catch statement to validate the input letters. An error message should be printed in case the user inputs an invalid letter.

I have two methods: showMenu and selectOperation.

The methods:

```
//Show Operations in menu
void showMenu() 
{
 cout << " Select an option:  \n\n"
     << "1 = Register new customers  \n"
     << "2 = Register new products   \n"
     << "3 = Add Product Existence   \n"
     << "4 = Register a new purchase \n"
     << "0 = Exit \n\n"; 
}


//Select an Operation from menu
int selectOperation() 
{
    int selectedOperation = 0;
    do
    {
        showMenu(); 
        cin >> selectedOperation;
        if ((selectedOperation < 0) || (selectedOperation > 4))
        {
            cout << "\n You have selected an invalid option"
            << "...Try again \n";
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }
    } while ((selectedOperation < 0) || (selectedOperation > 4));
    return selectedOperation;
}
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Do not use exceptions to control the regular flow of a program.

Comment: try/catch is not really intended for that sort of thing. You should write a function that either returns a valid letter, or re-prompts the user for input.

Comment: Your question is like asking how you drive a car with a spoon. You _could_ do that, but it's not sensible and would make things unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: In my opinion, using a try-catch statement is not the better way, it is the more complicated way, which is unrequired for your purposes.

Comment: "Can you guide me" is not a valid question. Please ask a specific question about a language feature or error message.

Comment: If you really want to handle that with exceptions check [`std::basic_ios::exceptions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions). You have to clear the input stream in any way from `fail()` state.

Answer (score 1):

You usually don't want to get and handle [exceptions for invalid input](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions).
Using exceptions to control regular flow of a program is a well known [design flaw/anti pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why). 
The idiomatic way is to check the input streams state:

```
 // is true for non integer input and numbers outside the valid range
 while(!(cin>>selectedOperation)) { 
     // Cleanup the stream state
     cin.clear();
     std::string dummy;
     cin >> dummy; // Consume the invalid input
     cout << "Please input a number." << std::endl;
 }
```

---

The exception variant looks like this (way more complicated and less concise IMO):

```
 cin.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit);
 bool validInput;
 do {
     try {
         validInput = true;
         cin>>selectedOperation)
     }
     catch (std::ios_base::failure &fail) {
         validInput = false;
         // Cleanup the stream state
         cin.clear();
         std::string dummy;
         cin >> dummy; // Consume the invalid input
         cout << "Please input a number." << std::endl;
     } 
 } while (!validInput);
```

You have to clear the input stream in any way from `fail()` state.

Comment: I'm basic beginner in c++. Thanks, I suposse.

Answer (score -1):

You could also do this with a if else if statement...

Comment: The `cin` stream goes to `fail()` state if something non numeric is read, so what do you intend to check with the `if else if` statement?

Comment: Good point ,I didnt realize that

Comment: This answer should be a comment. If you want to answer a question you should give a full answer, not a suggestion.